# Problem configuring Eclipse to use Glassfish

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I installed Eclipse 2020-09 using the Installer with JVM 14.0.2. I'm having trouble configuring it to use a local Glassfish 4.1 server.

I installed the Glassfish server adapter using Install New Software and URL https://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.1/repository/. This includes Sapphire which I have seen is a prerequisite.

I try to create a server but it fails. The following are in the error log:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext cannot be found by org.eclipse.glassfish.tools_1.0.1.201904090220
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:516)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core 4 0 2020-11-10 15:12:11.366
!MESSAGE One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core 4 0 2020-11-10 15:12:11.366
!MESSAGE Cannot install project facet Java 1.8. Some version of this project facet is already installed.

I've tried various JDKs and installing the server adapter from a ZIP file, without success.

Steve

Comment: Looks like https://bugs.eclipse.org/567300.

Comment: Thanks for your help @nitind